# Bracketing strategy on Tradingview

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, back-testing

I have Strategy in pine script and I am testing it on tradingview but my startegy use 1 min chart so tradingview does not provide so much data for 1 min chart even if I purchase to premium...

So is their any way where I can test this strategy with more historical 1 min Data.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [deep backtesting](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/?solution=43000666199) which is in beta version as of today. In order to use that, you are going to need a premium account.

> Deep Backtesting is an additional mode of operation of the Strategy
> Tester, which makes it possible to calculate the strategy on all
> historical data available for the selected symbol, and not only on
> those loaded on the chart.